# split the statement in a excel file column using a specific keyword

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with data in  multiple columns. i need to select one column from the file and separate the data in each cell of that column using a specific keyword in the cell. 
The keyword is same for each cell

[image]

Now what i want to do is, i want to separate each alphabet from the cell and give them a title like the one in the image below

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the structure of your spreadsheet?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you want to do once you have identified the cells in question? Copy them elsewhere? Sort them? I suggest you edit your answer providing a bit more detail about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Daniel
I have updated the question, please have a look at it and give me some idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following VBA code should do the trick:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MainSub()

Dim arr As Variant
Dim srcRow As Long, destRow As Long
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet

Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Before:=wsSrc)

wsDest.Cells(1, 1).Value2 = "Letter"
wsDest.Cells(1, 2).Value2 = "Value"
destRow = 2

For srcRow = 1 To wsSrc.Cells(wsSrc.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If InStr(1, wsSrc.Cells(srcRow, 1).Value2, "half:", vbTextCompare) Then
        arr = Split(wsSrc.Cells(srcRow, 1).Value2, "half:")(0)
        arr = Split(arr, "/")
        destRow = WriteToDest(arr, "FULL", destRow, wsDest)
        arr = Split(wsSrc.Cells(srcRow, 1).Value2, "half:")(1)
        arr = Split(arr, "/")
        destRow = WriteToDest(arr, "HALF", destRow, wsDest)
    Else
        arr = Split(wsSrc.Cells(srcRow, 1).Value2, "/")
        destRow = WriteToDest(arr, "FULL", destRow, wsDest)
    End If
Next srcRow

End Sub

Private Function WriteToDest(arr As Variant, HalfOrFull As String, destRow As Long, wsDest As Worksheet) As Long

Dim element As Long

For element = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If Trim(arr(element)) <> vbNullString Then
        wsDest.Cells(destRow, 1).Value2 = UCase(Trim(arr(element)))
        wsDest.Cells(destRow, 2).Value2 = "FULL"
        destRow = destRow + 1
    End If
Next element

WriteToDest = destRow

End Function
```

Just copy all of it into an empty module and adjust the name of the sheet in `Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` to the actual name of the sheet where the data resides.

The above code will then insert a new sheet and process / output the data as described in your post above.

Comment: Thank you @Ralph. It worked but i want to know what changes should i need to do if i want to select the second column and not the first one.

Comment: @Vinzy you should note that this website is not a free code-writing service. The fact that I helped you anyway is due to the fact that I had a bit of spare time and wanted to help you get started. Don't get used to this. This is very rare and most likely not even well regarded. So, in a first step, I suggest that you follow the general rules of this site and [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) (if it solved your problem as stated above). This will indicate to other users on this site that this problem is solved and doesn't require their attention anymore.

Comment: Afterwards, I'd suggest that you start reading the code carefully and try to understand it (own it). Note, that the blue words in the code are key-words. You can highlight them and then press `F1`  to get help on these words (to understand what they do). Also, you might want to read this in order to get a basic idea of VBA: http://www.homeandlearn.org/ Afterwards, you should be able to understand the code and adjust it yourself to any upcoming needs. Still, if you are running once again into problems, don't hesitate to come back (with your newly gained knowledge) and ask for more help.

Comment: i will read and go through the code and will come back if i have any new issue.